axios.post fails to follow proxy setup but not all of them in Vue
I set up a proxy in vite.config.ts:
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import vueJsx from '@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx'
import VueDevTools from 'vite-plugin-vue-devtools'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    vueJsx(),
    VueDevTools(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:5000',
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: path => path.replace(/^\/api/, ''),
      },
    },
  }
})

This is my app.ts code looks like:
app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { username, email, password } = req.body;
        console.log(username, email, password);
        let user = await User.findOne({ $or: [{ username }, { email }] });
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: 'User not found' });
        }
        const isPasswordMatch = await user.comparePassword(password);
        if (!isPasswordMatch) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Invalid password' });
        }
        const userInfo = { id: user._id, username: user.username, email: user.email };
        const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET!, { expiresIn: '1h' });
        res.cookie('token', token, { httpOnly: true, maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 });
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Login successful', user: userInfo });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Login failed', error });
    }
});

const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/newpost', upload.array('media'), async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { username, caption, price, status, location } = req.body;
        const media = (req.files as Express.Multer.File[]).map(file => ({
            media: file.buffer.toString('base64')
        }));
        const newPost = new Post({ username, caption, price, status, location, uploaded: media });
        await newPost.save();
        res.status(201).json({ message: 'Post created successfully', post: newPost });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Post creation failed', error });
    }
});

My axios.post in this function works fine:
const postNewPost = async () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('username', 'testuser');
    formData.append('caption', caption.value);
    formData.append('status', selectedStatus.value);
    formData.append('price', price.value?.toString() || '');
    formData.append('location', location.value);
    
    selectedMedia.value.forEach((file) => {
        formData.append('media', file);
    });
    try {
        const response = await axios.post('/api/newpost', formData, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            },
        });
        alert('Post created successfully!');
        emit('post-created');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
};

But it does not work in this function:
const loginUser = async () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    const { value: usernameEmailValue } = usernameEmail;
    if (emailRegex.test(usernameEmailValue)) {
        formData.append('email', usernameEmailValue);
    } else {
        formData.append('username', usernameEmailValue);
    }
    formData.append('password', passwordLogin.value);
    try {
        const response = await axios.post('/api/login', formData);
        if (response.status === 200) {
            alert('Login successful');
        } else {
            alert('Login failed');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Login failed:', error);
    }
};

when it fails to follow the proxy rule. In console, it says:
POST http://localhost:5173/api/login 500 (Internal Server Error)
Why does this happen even though these functions look almost the same?

What did make you think that it's proxy that is the problem? Looks like regular 500, which is expected, considering res.status(500)

Well, strangely, after I mess up the function and then rewrite it again exactly the same, it just works. I have no clue how to explain this.
